# Question about Anti Symmetricity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If there are no relations on the set R where (a,b) ∈ R and (b,a) ∈ R is it anti symmetrical because you can't evaluate if a = b or is it not anti-symmetrical because you can't evaluate if a = b?

ex)
R = {(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)}
I don't see a relation where (a,b) and (b,a) ∈ R so I can't evaluate if a = b

Answer (score 1):

This relation is antisymmetric. If there is no $a,b \in R$ such that $a\neq b$ and where both $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$, then $R$ is antisymmetric.

For this particular relation, the only four times we have both $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$ are where $a=b$, namely:

\begin{eqnarray*}
a=1, \; b=1 && \qquad \text{since $(1,1) \in R$} \\
a=2, \; b=2 && \qquad \text{since $(2,2) \in R$} \\
a=3, \; b=3 && \qquad \text{since $(3,3) \in R$} \\
a=4, \; b=4 && \qquad \text{since $(4,4) \in R$}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}